# Select a property in the property grid

Tags: c#, propertygrid

I am using a `PropertyGrid` to display the content of an object to the user.

This `PropertyGrid` is synchronized with an Excel sheet, assuming a cell value match a property value.

As the user selects a property in the `PropertyGrid`, the application highlights the corresponding cell in the Excel sheet which is opened beside. I can do this using the `SelectedGridItemChanged` event.

Now, I want to **have a property selected in my PropertyGrid** when the user selects a cell in the Excel sheet.

```
void myWorkbook_SheetSelectionChangeEvent(NetOffice.COMObject Sh, Excel.Range Target)
{
    if (eventMask > 0)
        return;

    try
    {
        eventMask++;

        this.Invoke(new Action(() => 
        {
            propertyGrid1.SelectedGridItem = ... // ?
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        eventMask--;
    }
}
```

I noticed that the `SelectedGridItem` can be written to.

Unfortunately I do not find a way to access the `GridItems` collection of my `PropertyGrid` so I can look for the right GridItem and select it.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all the GridItems from the root. I am using the below code to retrieve all the griditems within a property grid

```
private GridItem Root
    {
        get
        {
            GridItem aRoot = myPropertyGrid.SelectedGridItem;
            do
            {
                aRoot = aRoot.Parent ?? aRoot;
            } while (aRoot.Parent != null);
            return aRoot;
        }
    }
```

and pass the root to the below method

```
private IList<GridItem> GetAllChildGridItems(GridItem theParent)
    {
        List<GridItem> aGridItems = new List<GridItem>();
        foreach (GridItem aItem in theParent.GridItems)
        {
            aGridItems.Add(aItem);
            if (aItem.GridItems.Count > 0)
            {
                aGridItems.AddRange(GetAllChildGridItems(aItem));
            }
        }
        return aGridItems;
    }
```

Comment: ... then I can use the PropertyDescriptor property to get the GridItem I want, then I can do a Select(). If only I could upvote twice... The only quirck I had is that my PropertyGrid is empty sometimes so I have to check if a GridItem is selected before applying this. Brilliant! Thank you very much. Indeed. And by the way, welcome to the SO community.

Answer (score 0):

I came up against this quite a bit a project so I wrote an extension method for it:

```
if (!SetupManagerSettings.BootStrapperLocation.IsFile()) // Just another extension method to check if its a file
{
    settingsToolStripMenuItem.Checked = true;  // Event handler OnChecked ensures the settings panel is unhidden
    settingsPropertyGrid.ActivateControl();

    settingsPropertyGrid.SelectPropertyGridItemByName("BootStrapperLocation"); // Here is the extension method 

    return false;
}
```

Here is the extension method with a private, supporting method for traversing the hierarchy of objects (if this applies to your object model):

```
    public static bool SelectPropertyGridItemByName(this PropertyGrid propertyGrid, string propertyName)
    {
        MethodInfo getPropEntriesMethod = propertyGrid.GetType().GetMethod("GetPropEntries", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        Debug.Assert(getPropEntriesMethod != null, @"GetPropEntries by reflection is still valid in .NET 4.6.1 ");

        GridItemCollection gridItemCollection = (GridItemCollection)getPropEntriesMethod.Invoke(propertyGrid, null);

        GridItem gridItem = TraverseGridItems(gridItemCollection, propertyName);

        if (gridItem == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        propertyGrid.SelectedGridItem = gridItem;

        return true;
    }

    private static GridItem TraverseGridItems(IEnumerable parentGridItemCollection, string propertyName)
    {
        foreach (GridItem gridItem in parentGridItemCollection)
        {
            if (gridItem.Label != null && gridItem.Label.Equals(propertyName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {                   
                return gridItem;
            }

            if (gridItem.GridItems == null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            GridItem childGridItem = TraverseGridItems(gridItem.GridItems, propertyName);

            if (childGridItem != null)
            {
                return childGridItem;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the above options and did not like them that much, I altered it a bit found that this works well for me

```
bool TryFindGridItem(PropertyGrid grid, string propertyName, out GridItem discover)
{
    if (grid is null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(grid));
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("You need to provide a property name", nameof(propertyName));
    }

    discover = null;
    var root = pgTrainResult.SelectedGridItem;
    while (root.Parent != null)
        root = root.Parent;

    foreach (GridItem item in root.GridItems)
    {
        //let's not find the category labels 
        if (item.GridItemType!=GridItemType.Category)
        {
            if (match(item, propertyName))
            {
                discover= item;
                return true;

            }
        }
        //loop over sub items in case the property is a group

        foreach (GridItem child in item.GridItems)
        {
            if (match(child, propertyName))
            {
                discover= child;
                return true;
            }
        }


        //match based on the property name or the DisplayName if set by the user
        static bool match(GridItem item, string name)
            => item.PropertyDescriptor.Name.Equals(name, StringComparison.Ordinal) || item.Label.Equals(name, StringComparison.Ordinal);


    }
    return false;
}
```

it uses a local method named match, if you're version of C# does not allow it then just put it external to the method and perhaps give it a better name.

Match looks at the DisplayName as well as the property name and returns true if either is a match, this might not be what you would like so then update that.

In my usecase I need to select the property based on a value the user can select so call the above method like this:

```
if (TryFindGridItem(pgMain, propertyName, out GridItem gridItem))
{                
     gridItem.Select();
}
```

It could theoretically never not find it unless the user selects a string that is not proper this way the if can be updated using an else .. I rather keep it safe then have a null-pointer exception if I can't find the name specified.

Also I am not going into sub classes and lists of classes as my use case doesn't need that, if yours does than perhaps make recursive calls in the GridItem.

Small note, replace **GridItem** with **var** and the code brakes as at compile time the IDE has no clue what a GridItemCollection returns…